# Apache Redirect using Regex

Tags: regex, apache

Instead of doing a
`Redirect permanent / https://example.com/`

I'd like to redirect everything except a one particular directory using Regex. Let say the directory in question is `bar` and the link can be something like `http://example.com/foo/bar/something.html`.

So anything that has `bar` will not be redirected. Everything else will.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind ya'll.. so much negativity to help someone.
Figured it out myself.

`RedirectMatch permanent "^((?!bar).)*$" https://example.com/`

Hope this can help someone.